# Upload file on server with JS only

Tags: javascript, file-upload

I'm looking for a method to Upload a file on my server using **Javascript only**.
I've already tried some method with **formData** that I found on the forum, but nothing works.

```
var fileChoose = document.getElementById('file-select');

form.onsubmit =  async function(event) {
event.preventDefault();


// Récupère le fichier sélectionné
var files = fileChoose.files;

// Création d'un objet FormData
var formData = new FormData();
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
filesConfig = files[0]; // Ajoute le fichier dans une variable

formData.append('fileLoad', filesConfig);

try {
  let r = await fetch('./Files', {method: "POST", body: formData});
  console.log("HTTP response code:",r.status);
  console.log(r);
} catch(e) {
  console.log("Il y'a une erreur...: ", e);
}
```

This method tells me that the file is successfully sent, but I can't find the file on my server.

**Any idea?**

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [Ajax](https://skillcrush.com/2018/04/26/what-is-ajax/).

How to make [Ajax Request](https://dev.to/nikola/making-ajax-calls-in-pure-javascript-the-old-way-ed5)

Ajax can call a function from the **Server-Side language** without loading the page.

So you write the function in your Server-Side language than pass the date via Ajax to the function.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is **Client-Side**. You will not be able to upload files to a **Server** with it. You would need a **Server-Side** language, such as PHP.

[Article on Client vs Server Side](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/serverless/glossary/client-side-vs-server-side/)

Comment: .......or Javascript...... (Node.js) This answer is wrong IMO